# How to transpose 3D array to make n feature vectors?

Tags: python, numpy

If I had an array that contained three different arrays of features as so(written in pseudocode but using numpy:

```
height = [6.2,5.8,5.9,5.5]
weight = [50,100,125,40]
age = [18,25,45,73]
ftrs = [height,weight,age]
```

And I wanted to create n feature vectors, how would I reshape and transpose the array? So, for example, the first feature vector would contain:

```
[height[0],weight[0],age[0]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: `list(zip(height,weight,age))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.c_[height,weight,age]`

Hope that answerd you question.
The function makes use of low level implementation and should be quiet fast.
Here is the doc https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html

Answer (score 0):

```
In [378]: height = [6.2,5.8,5.9,5.5]
     ...: weight = [50,100,125,40]
     ...: age = [18,25,45,73]
     ...: ftrs = [height,weight,age]
In [379]: ftrs
Out[379]: [[6.2, 5.8, 5.9, 5.5], [50, 100, 125, 40], [18, 25, 45, 73]]
```

We can simply make an array from the list of lists:

```
In [380]: arr = np.array(ftrs)
In [381]: arr
Out[381]: 
array([[  6.2,   5.8,   5.9,   5.5],
       [ 50. , 100. , 125. ,  40. ],
       [ 18. ,  25. ,  45. ,  73. ]])
In [382]: arr[:,0]
Out[382]: array([ 6.2, 50. , 18. ])
```

Columns of the array are your 'feature vectors', which can be simply accessed with `numpy` array indexing.

Or you could transpose the array, making the features rows:

```
In [383]: arrt = arr.transpose()
In [384]: arrt
Out[384]: 
array([[  6.2,  50. ,  18. ],
       [  5.8, 100. ,  25. ],
       [  5.9, 125. ,  45. ],
       [  5.5,  40. ,  73. ]])
In [385]: arrt[0]
Out[385]: array([ 6.2, 50. , 18. ])
```

Equivalently you could column stack the lists (`np.c_` does that):

```
In [386]: np.stack(ftrs, axis=1)
Out[386]: 
array([[  6.2,  50. ,  18. ],
       [  5.8, 100. ,  25. ],
       [  5.9, 125. ,  45. ],
       [  5.5,  40. ,  73. ]])
```

The `list(zip` mentioned in a comment is a well known way of 'transposing' a list of lists.  If you don't otherwise need `numpy` it's a good tool to know.

In [387]: list(zip(*ftrs))
Out[387]: [(6.2, 50, 18), (5.8, 100, 25), (5.9, 125, 45), (5.5, 40, 73)]